# PostgreSQL call coming back empty

Tags: c#, postgresql

Currently trying to query a PostgreSQL database for some information. Here's the code I'm currently using for troubleshooting:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string connstring = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};",
                                  "[PLACEHOLDERFORSO]","[PLACEHOLDERFORSO]","[PLACEHOLDERFORSO]","[PLACEHOLDERFORSO]","[PLACEHOLDERFORSO]");
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
string sql = "select * from pg_user";
NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);

conn.Open();
da.Fill(ds);
dt = ds.Tables[0];
conn.Close();
```

I put all of this in a trycatch and it never drops down to the catch.... but it receives zero data back. When I run the query on the database directly, I get my expected results.

Additionally, I reconnected to the database in PGAdmin and all of my credentials worked just fine - I copy/pasted them from the code just to make sure I didn't have any typos.

I looked at [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30989/Using-PostgreSQL-in-your-C-NET-application-An-intr) tutorial, and I'm essentially doing the same thing; by all accounts, it appears as though the code *should* work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Just a simple select statement. `SELECT DISTINCT <column_name> FROM <schema.view>`

Comment: I've modified it to use a common command, which also returns zero results when run from my program, but works just fine in PGAdmin.